# contour plot within a loop in R

Tags: r, plot

Despite i get to plot contours one by one, i have an error message when plotting them within a loop or using sapply

Here is my data frame:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2xmcc8zsb0wufk/df.csv

```
require(akima)
require(fields)
for (i in 0:10)  
{ 
  h=levels(loggers$hour)[i] 
  x=loggers[loggers$hour==h,6]
  y=loggers[loggers$hour==h,7]
  z=loggers[loggers$hour==h,
### Interpolate
tmp = interp(x,y,z)
### Plot interpolation
contour(tmp, add=F)
}
```

Any hint?
Thanks in advance
Agus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code. `z=loggers[loggers$hour==h,` is missing a bracket. Also when you say `for (i in 0:10)` you get `h=levels(loggers$hour)[0]` which returns `character(0)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry and thanks Curtis, that made me advance a lot. I now got to                                                                for (i in 1:length(levels(loggers$hour)))  
    { 

h=levels(loggers$hour)[i]
      
      upperTset=40.9# T. helenae
      
      x=loggers[loggers$hour==h,6]
      y=loggers[loggers$hour==h,7]
      z=loggers[loggers$hour==h,3]-upperTset
### Interpolate
tmp = interp(x,y,z)
### Plot interpolation
contour(tmp, add=F,main=h)
}                                                                   but still does not plot some of the levels

Comment: interestingly, sapply also jumps the levels of (loggers$hour), despite each of them are plottable by hand:            sapply(levels(loggers$hour),function(h){
             x=loggers[loggers$hour==h,6]
             y=loggers[loggers$hour==h,7]
             z=loggers[loggers$hour==h,3]-upperTset
             
             tmp = interp(x,y,z)
             contour(tmp, add=F,main=h)})

Comment: @ Agus Glad I could help you a bit. Try this `sort.hour <- loggers[order(loggers$hour) , ]` It will help you sort your data. if you wanted to sort by location `<- loggers[order(loggers$location) , ]` You can see when sorting by hours that 9:00, 9:05 etc are placed at the end. I'm sure there is a way around this but you could switch to decimal hours 9.00, 9.0833, 9.1666 etc.